# odoo v8: publish website on another domain

Tags: ubuntu, odoo

I am using ubuntu 12.04 with an installed version of odoo v8.  I am using the new module website builder.  I want to publish what I have created to my domain but I do not know how to do it.

Any pointers please?

Comment: u need  a cloud server to install odoo and restore your local database dump

Comment: okay. so since I have an external cloud server, how do I connect this instance of a website builder to an existing domain that I alreay own? Also, if I just use a cloud service, do you advise me to change the port to port 80 using the

Comment: which cheap ubuntu cloud services do you recommend?

Comment: i prefer you digitalocean which i m using now https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=4571fde21fc1

Comment: Forwarding port u can use nginx server https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-odoo-formerly-openerp-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps/ if you don't want ssl just comment them